Illegal pattern character 'o' in to_timestamp call
I'm trying to convert my string field to date field in my Databricks 10.4 LTS. So I wrote following query
select to_timestamp(joiningDate,'Mon DD YYYY hh:MI a') from employee

My sample JoiningData contains data in below format
|joiningDate           |
|                      |
________________________
| Mar 15 1978 2:15 PM  |
| Apr 12 1983 11:11 AM |  

But I'm getting error message saying that
IllegalArgumentException:Illegal pattern character 'o'
Can you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Databricks uses "MMM" for (abbreviated) month names, not "Mon".

Try using the datetime pattern of 'MMM DD YYYY hh:mm a'
select to_timestamp(joiningDate,'MMM DD YYYY hh:mm a') from employee

Here is the the link to the datetime patterns used in Databricks.
